# Command to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I need to upgrade Ubuntu Server to version 12.04 with no GUI. Is there a way to upgrade to that specific version, somewhere along the line of do-release-upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you will need to back up all the data.

- Type the following command

> $ uname -mrs
>
> $ lsb_release -a

The following is the sample output:

```
Linux 3.2.0-51-generic x86_64
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Type the following command to update package list and instal the update-manager-core package if it is not already installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Next, type the following command to upgrade the Ubuntu server to the latest release such as LTS 14.04 from the command-line. This is the recommended command as the server has no graphic environment or if the server is to be upgraded over a remote connection using ssh client:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The do-release-upgrade will launch the upgrade tool. You need to follow the on-screen instructions.  The following message may pop up:

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release No new release found

To force upgrade pass the -d option to sudo do-release-upgrade command:

> sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Finally reboot the system:

> $ sudo reboot

Verify your settings:

> $ lsb_release -a
>
> $ uname -mrs
>
> $ tail -f /var/log/app/log/file

I hope this will help

Comment: Won't this upgrade to the latest version? I can't see a specified version anywhere in there. I'm in 10.4.4 now and I need to run 12.04.